# Draw image in cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, draw

I have main function where i draw background:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backg.png"];

        background.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 1);

        background.position = ccp(size.width, size.height);
        [self addChild:background z:-1];

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and function where i get touch and then have logic for the program. But i don't know how can i draw from her.

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    int a[3][3],fail,hod,i,k,win,x,y;

    for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
    {
        for(k=1; k<=3; k++)
        {
            a[i][k]=0;
        }
    }

    win=0;
    hod=1;

    while(win==0)
    {
        if(hod%2==1)
        {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
            location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
            x=location.x;
            y=location.y;
            NSLog(@"%d %d",x,y);
            //here i should draw
            hod++;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i draw one image from second function upside background which place in first function?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2D you don't draw things. You add or remove nodes (sprites, labels, etc.). You can reposition them. You can reorder their z order to change which is in front of which other node. But the drawing is done by Cocos2D internally.

There are some exceptions of course but custom drawing is limited to the -(void) draw method and something tells me you don't actually want to start drawing things with OpenGL.